# Facebook: share custom story doesn't appear in the wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having problems with the way the custom story that I have is displayed on Facebook.

It's working fine but instead of publishing on the wall of the user, it appears in the Recent Activity section.

The steps I follow until now:

- create the custom action 'Want'
- set the 'Explicitly Shared' option on
- run this code:

  ```
          FB.api(
                'me/mynamespace:want',
                'post',
                {
                    article: "https://developers.facebook.com/docs?locale=es_LA"
                },
                function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
          );
  ```

Can anyone help me?

If you need more info let me know. Thanks

Comment: You don't set explicitly shared to on. You need to do that in the API call

Comment: Great @WizKid! You should answer the question (not in a comment) so I can mark it as the correct one ;) Thanks! This is the code I was missing after 'article' property: 'fb:explicitly_shared': true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't set explicitly shared to on. You need to do that in the API call.